# Connecting to running docker containers from localhost

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, docker, docker-machine

I have just installed **docker** & **docker machine** on mac os X.

I have two running containers I would like to connect to from my terminal:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
5a15af29232f        mysql:latest        "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes                  0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   hopeful_fermi
967f240e77d1        elasticsearch       "/docker-entrypoint.s"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour               9200/tcp, 9300/tcp       jolly_swartz
```

I am not sure how to connect to elasticsearch and mysql from my mac os X terminal...

I have tried `docker inspect` on both containers in order to determine what was the IP address and connecting to the containers using that IP address to no avail.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But keep in mind you need to use the IP address of `docker-machine` instead of `localhost`.

To get it simply type `docker-machine ip <machineName>`.

**Edit**: For each service that you want to connect you need to expose the ports via a mapping like `docker run -d ... -p 3306:3306 ...`. That would make it possible to connect with the mysql client like `mysql -u <user> -h 192.168.99.100 -p`. In case of elasticsearch you need to do `docker run -d ... -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 ...`. For more details please have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/).

Comment: And then how do connect to Elasticsearch and Mysql? Can I just use `mysql -h 192.168.99.100 -u root` where *192.168.99.100* is the IP?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the elasticsearch port mappings.

Comment: I was able to successfully connect to ES.

Comment: And to Mysql too! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try `docker exec -it 5a1 bash` to get ibto the first, and `docker exec -it 967 bash` to get into the other one

Comment: He is explicitly asking for connecting to an IP address. Not to execute a shell inside the container.